# I need the macro to apply only to a range of cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range, getlasterror

I need the macro to take as reference var targetRange =targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1,1); but only from a range of cells, from 1 to 7.
because I need to write in front of the data that the macro brings to me
when using getLastRow()+1 it takes everything I write in the sheet and continues copying the same information.

i like app script but i need more assistance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| 2 | 1 | 8 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 10 | 9 | 8 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 5 | 7 | 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 9 | 8 | 8 | 2 | 8 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 9 | 8 |

```
function getvaluesfromARangeofCells() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const [[a1,,,,,,,,,],[,b2,,,,,,,,],[,,c3,,,,,,],[,,,d4,,,,,]] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log("a1: %s, b2:%s, c3:%s, d4: %s",a1,b2,c3,d4);
}

xecution log
5:06:07 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:05:58 PM  Info    a1: COL1, b2:8.0, c3:8.0, d4: 2.0
5:06:10 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```